# Led as an input photodiode [Arduino AVR]

Tags: led, sensor, diodes, timer, input

I’m trying to use a LED as a light sensor(input) connected to a Arduino Nano.
I connected the led with the Anode at digital pin 8 (PB0) with a resistance of 56 Ohm and the Cathode at an analog pin A0 (PC0).
[image: schematics_led_input]
    The main idea is to measure the voltage across the parasite capacitance in the LED which was stored during a short 5V pulse(turning PC0 high and then low) in reverse bias.
    First example is very simple.

```
uint16_t sen_time = 0;    //Variable for counting
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Setting pin 8 to OUTPUT and the rest to INPUT
  DDRB |= (1 << PB0);   // Setting OUTPUT PB0
  PORTB &=  ~(1 << PB0);   // Setting Anode LOW 

  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10); // Setting timer, no prescaling(f = 16Mhz)
}

void loop() {
/* Reverse bias pulse */
  DDRC |= (1 << PC0);     //Setting A0 to OUTPUT
  PORTC |= (1 << PC0);    //Setting A0 to HIGH
 /* Setting Threestate Cathode */ 
  DDRC &=  ~(1 << PC0);    //Setting A0 to INPUT
  PORTC &=  ~(1 << PC0);   //Setting A0 to LOW

  TCNT1 = 0;  // Setting timer the moment we turn off 
  //Waiting for the led to discharge and counting
  while (analogRead(A0) != 0)
  {
    sen_time++;
  }
  Serial.print("TCNT:");
  Serial.println(TCNT1);
  Serial.print("sen_time:");
  Serial.println(sen_time);    //Print the value
  sen_time = 0;                //Setting the value to 0
}
```

The results are as follows.
In normal conditions:
[image: normal_conditions_data]
In darkness:
[image: darkness_data]
In heavy light:
[image: heavy_light_data]

The variable which is incremented sen_time is pretty much accurate, having high values for darkness and low values for heavy light. But I can’t understand why my timer has trash values all way around.

I’m trying to solve it with interrupts(Pin change interrupts) but getting the pin three-stated just triggers the interrupt all way around. Plus the TCNT got trush values whenever I read it. Getting pull-up resistors just keeps the pin high.
Some advices about how to solve this problem preferably with interrupts (due to time restriction on future project). Thank you and I hope to solve it as soon as possible!

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the value TCNT1 into a variable straight after your **while** loop and before you start printing stuff, then print the value of that variable.

Why? TCNT1 is counting at 16MHz. Your serial port baud rate is 9600.  A single character (start bit, 8 data bits, stop bit) will therefore take ~10.4ms to transmit. In this amount of time, TCNT1 will increment 16,666 times. In the time 4 characters take to transmit, TCNT1 will wrap around and start counting up from zero again.